# Loading a document with PDF box 2.0 causing torubles

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Ive been experimenting with a pdf box 2.0 and i seem to be getting stuck at the very beginning. The basic

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
```

Seems to be causing issues. The PDDocument object is created but everything inside of it seems to be null, like documentCatalog, documentId, pageMap...
This works perfectly fine on 1.8.9, with the same document ive been trying to load into 2.0.

Has anyone got any ideas? Should do some manual configuration of pdf box?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the error you got?

Comment: The error im getting comes from the next line of code which is: `PDpage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0)` . And the error is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog.getPages()Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageTree

Comment: Did you include new PDF box  jar correctly in your class path?

Comment: I added the maven dependency from pdf box website. Namely the:

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>`
and the repository that is listed that needs to be added to pom.xml, and have the .jar on my classpath. I have read about adding other .jars like levigo JBIG2, but i am not sure wether i need it yet because i dod not get to the processing part at all.

Comment: Have you looked what's in your local repository?

Comment: I have checked my local repo, and i have pdfbox-app 2.0 jar in there.

Comment: It is definitely something with the project setup since i have built a small standalone app that uses the same .jar and everything works like a charm.
Thanks!